# Random programs appearing in Applications menu--- did I get hacked?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, appmenu

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on Wayland. Yesterday, I was using my computer when it suddenly went to the login menu, as if it had just been booted up. When I logged in and opened up a fresh desktop, the Applications menu had a bunch of icons that I'd never seen before, many of which were programs starting in "X". **Xvidtune**, **Xman**, **Xkill**, **Xconsole** to name a few. Also **pppconfig** and **pstree** among others.

[image]

The one thing I had installed before this happened was w3m in terminal, so maybe that was a cause? But when I used `sudo apt remove` to remove w3m, the programs were still there. I also did a partial upgrade (which I now know was a bad idea), but the programs were still there in the App menu.

How did these random programs get there? How can I remove them? Are they serving some purpose or are part of the OS that I shouldn't try to remove? Did someone hack into my computer?

Comment: Most of those utilities seem to have a relation to the [Xorg display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server), a piece of underlying infrastructure used by default on 18.04 (Wayland is an alternative choice, replacing it). Other items you mention also seem to be normal components of Linux systems, expected to be present on an Ubuntu install (do a web search on any/each of them). So they seem to be legit. As to what's the technical explanation on how they became exposed in your applications overview grid (what that w3m installation or partial upgrade did), I don't know.

Comment: Ok, to be very precise, those utilities are associated with the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), which X.org Server is an impementation of.

Comment: ty @Levente , I'm glad you think most of the programs seem legit. So far my computer has been functioning normally, so other than slight annoyances it seems good. I did a file search and Xorg display server and  X Window System showed a bunch of results, mostly in the /.wine directory.  If they're normal components of the OS should I just leave them be?

Comment: If I was in your place, I would remain to be irritated why they are there and would remain curious about a resolution. But I would not worry about a hack. Beyond that, there are 2 specifics of your system that I am not familiar with: I don't know how to make sense of Xorg files popping up when one is running on Wayland (maybe it's just a coincidence, as other, non-X-related files also had popped up?); I also don't have Wine installed, so no idea about its interference either...

Comment: don't get me wrong, I'm definitely still irritated! Just ran `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and I'm definitely on wayland. The funny thing is, I had a session going with a bunch of windows open, _and then_ it suddenly went to the login screen as if my computer had just booted up. That's when they appeared. So i bet something weird happened when it made that sudden jump to the login screen, which is what made me worried about a hack.  As a side note, the wine files are still there but I never got wine working.